# wall outlet when bottom is tiled and top is drywall

Tags: switch

Our handyman may have planned poorly when tiling the bottom half of our bathroom wall.  The light outlet's bottom is within the tiled area, white the top half is within the drywall.  There is a space of about an inch behind the switch and the drywall that needs to be filled with something.  Another tile?  I would love to send you a picture and hear your suggestions for this design nightmare.

Comment: Please edit your post to post a picture, or post a link to a picture and someone else will edit it in for you. If your "handyman" did this, and made the choice of where to stop the tiles himself, step one is to call him in and inquire how he intends to make it acceptable to you. Preferably before payment is exchanged for the tiling job.

Comment: Becky, please attach a picture to your query, I (we) cannot form an adequate mental picture of the situation based on your description.

Comment: Adding a picture to your post is easy.  just click "edit" and then click the little photo icon (5th from the left)

Answer (score 2):

There are only three options:

1. Move the light switch.
2. Install the tile differently.
3. Live with it.

The first and second options require additional tile work and possibly work to the gypsum board and the electrical system.

Comment: #3 is not a good suggestion as it is a code violation and pretty dangerous condition for a bathroom.

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion. It was an objective fact. Without a picture, I am not presuming that the contents of an electrical box are exposed, particularly when the question is centered around aesthetic concern. There is no reason to assume work is being done in violation of building codes based on the presentation, however, I share your concern if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Some more options:

1. Attach a [receptacle box extender](http://www.homedepot.com/p/ReceptXtenders-1-Gang-3-4-in-Electrical-Receptacle-Box-Extension-Ring-00006/100185696) to the switch box.  Find some wood the same thickness as the tile+backer (you say one inch).  Fiberboard may be a good option as it won't splinter or split.  Cut it larger than the area needed under the face plate, router a [roundover](http://www.ptreeusa.com/images/Peach%20Graphics/router_bits/roundover_300.jpg) or other edge shape on the three exposed edges.  Cut an opening for the receptacle.  You'll have a 'U' shaped peice of wood at the end of all this.  Screw/glue it to the wall.  Fill the screw heads and chipouts with wood filler.  Caulk any gaps.  Prime it.  Paint it.  If you have bullnose or quarter-round tile installed at the top edge, you may want to router a matching [cove](http://www.ptreeusa.com/images/Peach%20Graphics/router_bits/cove_bit_300.jpg) shape where your wood piece meets the tile.  It's a ton of work for a small detail, it'll still look like an afterthought, and you'll need to be good with a router.
2. Get a Rotozip or Dremmel with a tile bit and cut away the tile to accommodate the face plate.  Easier, but uglier as you'll have exposed cut tile edge to look at.  There may be some bullnose edge treatments that you can bond to the tile to hide the edge.  You'll just need to cut away enough tile to fit.

Answer (score 0):

I would run a beed of caulk along the top edge of the tile, then around the outlet.  Either that, or cut the top edge of the outlet off so that it matched the height of the tile, then run a beed of caulk over the top of the tile and fill the gap in the outlet.  Those would be my two suggestions.  I ran into that issue tonight, but lucky for me I am using small tile squares, so I am going to do another row heigh, and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself on a backsplash. Mine is for two light switches together and my vertical line w/ wo tile goes through center of the switches.Can’t move box or divide to two separate switches, no other place for it,truly. Can’t live with it, caulk would be over 3/8” thick, mine is marble subway tile. It’s only 2” to end of counter and could back up the 2” to avoid but the opposite side is where sink is so I need it there and two inches short of countertop edge looks wrong, just wrong...so... I am going to bullnose around it. With the marble I hand sand with palm sander to make a pretty bullnose and can do any shape.Did 527 already, so a few extra aren’t a big deal at this point.I do this myself, but I’ve had this done professionally if you have someone in your area that bullnoses tile that’s ceramic or porcelain. Glass mosaic many times has a finished edge. If I were doing this on the horizontal version I would choose this same option but cut the tile narrower to go around top of outlet bullnosing &framing it.